.htaccess for hash-bang redirects
I have created a site which uses the /#!/ hashbang system of loading pages with javascript. My URLs all contain onclick handlers which return false, but the href tag itself goes to a real link. Here's an example:
<a href="/contact" onclick="loadPage('contact);return false;">Contact</a>
That function handles the communication with the server and everything works great.
I want to set up the .htaccess file (if possible) to redirect the non-javascript user (or spider) to the page which actually doesn't exist. I want the server to redirect the user to /#!/contact without giving a 404 response.
Here's what I've tried:
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /#!/$1 [L]

I anticipate that some will suggest that this is not the right approach, but aside from that is this even possible?
(some related pages which don't seem exactly relevant:)
.htaccess 301 Redirect Hash Tag Redirect
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133023/hash-url-rewrite-in-htaccess
.htaccess 301 Redirect Hash Tag Redirect

Taax, it's probably best to start using the HTML5 History API instead of hashbangs.
Then add to .htaccess add a number of rules:
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.html [L]

And then implement processing on the server without JS.
To make it a little clearer, about the first sentence.
Instead of using URLs with hashes (/# \ ! /contact), we will use clean URLs (/contact), and manage navigation using history.pushState\ () and popstate events.
P.S. I'm sorry if I didn't write a very nice response, but I was in a hurry.
